# How to save the new values from cells, not the old ones?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable in a JScrollPane and the data comes from a database. Cells are editable, and I want to save the new values (the edited ones) in the database. The problem is that *getValueAt(row, col)* returns the old, unedited values.

Here is the code that takes the values from cells and insert them in the database.

```
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int row = table.getEditingRow();
    if(row == -1) return -1;
    String name = tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
    String stringPrice = tableModel.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
    float price = Float.parseFloat(stringPrice);
    products.updateProduct(name, price);
    ...
    return 1;
```

And here is what I get in the *updateProduct(name, price)* method:

```
UPDATE products
SET `prod_name` = 'OLD_NAME', `prod_price` = 'OLD_PRICE'
WHERE `id` = 4
```

instead of:

```
UPDATE products
SET `prod_name` = 'NEW_NAME', `prod_price` = 'NEW_PRICE'
WHERE `id` = 4
```

There might be a simple solution, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen always or intermittently? I've seen this behavior in JTable: 1) you click on a cell, 2) edit it, 3) and hit "enter" or just click somewhere else. Until step 3) the table model doesn't change; seems that while cell editor is active, it doesn't propagate the value to the model.

Comment: It always happens... Now that you mention "enter", i tried to hit it and it works (after I changed getEditingRow() to getSelectedRow()), but i have to hit enter, and then click the Save button. It is possible to click directly Save after finishing editing, without hitting enter? Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how your code snipped is invoked I would guess that your problem is that the cell editor has not been stopped so the model has not yet been updated with the new data.

You can use a TableModelListener to be notified when data in a cell changes. Then you are guaranteed that the data in the model is correct.

Or, if you are using a "Save" button to update the database, then you need to read [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks.. I use a Save button indeed. I read the article you mentioned and using table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE); works. But only after the second cell edited, the first cell I edit won't lose focus when I click the Save button. And that's odd too, but I'll think about it.

Comment: @radu, you need to invoke the table.putClientProperty(...) when you create the table, NOT in the ActionListener.

Comment: The ActionListener calls a method, editProduct(), which contains the code above and creates the table model, not the table. I put the code in this method. I'll move it to where I first create the table.

Comment: @camickr it works as it should now.. thanks a lot.. would you be kind to explain me why was important to not put the putClientProperty() in the ActionListener? "terminateEditOnFocusLost" would then refer to the button?

Comment: The "terminateEditOnFocusLost" property basically adds a FocusListener to the table to invoke the stopCellEditing() method for you automatically when the table loses focus. If you add the code in the ActionListener method of the button then the table has already lost focus so the code will only work the next time the table loses focus.

Answer (score -1):

You could implement your own cell editor, and use its current value instead of the value in the model if it's active

Comment: -1, then you could be updating the database with invalid data. The user could click the Save button and then hit escape on the editor to cancel the update of the data to the model.